# Safe-aa-sdk getting error like execution reverted for tx with calldata like approve, transfer but works for send native gas(without data like "0x")

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, typescript, account-abstraction, safe

Hey team I am trying to execute tx like erc20 simple transaction by populate calldata and send or relayTransaction using safe-aa(4337). But it is getting error like execution reverted.

But safe-aa works for simple tx like sending eth or matic native token without data(data: "0x").
I am not sure what i am doing wrong. sending prefect gasLimit and data, toAddres and all but still getting error

sample tx with execution reverted
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x857915674db5caf273d6dff0627e12d95b168cd666a1481b8d6e3dc3778f9523

tell me please what i am doing wrong.

I am trying to reach out on discord as weel at setup channel of Safe Group.